# Debugging Angular2 applications

Tags: angular

I have a written a sample angular2 component in which initially closing tag
for "h2" element was missing in the template

```
@Component({
selector:'rx2',
template: `
<div><h2> RX2 component</h2></div>
`
})
```

And while executing the application in browser,only below error description was 
displayed in console.

> directive_normalizer.js:106Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:(…)

Because this is a small component with only 1 line for template,
I was able to identify the issue and fix it, my question is , is there any simpler way to identify such issues in case of a bigger templates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the following technique

**Step 1** - Click on `(...)`

[image]

**Step 2** - Find the error

[image]