# angular2 Validator Error: Template parse errors:(…)

Tags: javascript, validation, angular, ng-controller

I have problem. In console i can see "Error: Template parse errors:(…)". I'm use:

"@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.6",

"@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.6",

"@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.6",

My form looks like

```
    <form name="authForm" novalidate="" ng-submit="login()" class="md-padding" [ngFormModel]="form">
        <div layout="column" class="layout-column">
            <div class="md-form" style="margin-bottom: 64px; margin-top: 20px">
                <input ngControl="" class="mdl-textfield__input" [(ngModel)]="user.number" name="number" type="tel" (focus)="focus()" (blur)="focusOut()" [textMask]="{mask: mask}" id="number" required ngControl="number" #number="ngForm">
                <label class="mdl-textfield__label" [class.active]="user.number != null" for="number">Numer telefonu</label>
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="!number.valid" class="alert alert-danger">
                <span>Cos nei halo</span>
            </div>
            <div class="md-form" style="margin-bottom: 44px">
                <input class="mdl-textfield__input" [(ngModel)]="user.password" name="password" (focus)="focusPass()" (blur)="focusOutPass()" type="password" id="passInput" required>
                <label class="mdl-textfield__label" [class.active]="user.password != null" for="number">Hasło</label>
            </div>
            <a class="router" routerLink="/panel"><button (click)="logIn($event)" class="md-raised md-accent md-button md-ink-ripple " [class.active]="user.password != null && user.number != null" style="width: 320px" type="submit" aria-label="Zaloguj się"><span>Zaloguj się</span></button></a>
        </div>
    </form>
```

My .ts file

```
    import {Component, Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';
import {AngularFire, FirebaseObjectObservable} from 'angularfire2';
import {Http, Response} from '@angular/http';
import {UserDataService} from '../index';
import {LoginService} from "../login.service";
import { FormBuilder, ControlGroup, Control, Validators, FORM_PROVIDERS, FORM_DIRECTIVES } from 'angular2/common';


/**
 * This class represents the lazy loaded loginComponent.
 */
@Component({
    selector: 'box-login',
    templateUrl: 'login.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['login.component.css'],
})
export class LoginComponent {
    private user = {number: null, password: null};
    private firebaseSession: FirebaseObjectObservable<any>;
    public mask = ['+', /[1-9]/, /\d/, ' ', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, ' ', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, ' ', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/]

    @Output() notify: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

    form: ControlGroup;

    constructor(private af: AngularFire,private _LoginService: LoginService, private http: Http, private _userDataService: UserDataService, private formnbuilder: FormBuilder) {
        this.form = formnbuilder.group({
            number: ['', Validators.required],
            password: []
        })
    }
```

i dont know where is problem, im did this the same that another guys, they work, I do not

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40445595/debugging-angular2-applications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per angular [change log](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes-2) from angular 2.0.0-rc.6 forms APIs in `@angular/common` have been removed so importing `FORM_DIRECTIVES`, `FORM_PROVIDERS`, `FormBuilder` from `@angular/common` will not work.

Now angular 2.1.2 is released so its better to use latest angular version. you can check angular guides for updating your [forms](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html) and [form validation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/form-validation.html)

Comment: so, Is there any possibility to do validation in 2.0.0-rc.6"?

Comment: i think you need to import from `@angular/forms` instead of `@angular/common`. Also the name of directives are also changed in rc6 so you need to change the name and the way you have used the form directives like `ngForm`, `ngFormModel`. So its better you check the change log first before you make any change .