# Angular2: unable to display component template in another (uncaught parse error)

Tags: html, angular

i'm trying to display a very simple component using angular2.  When I run the server (using ng-cli) I get the following error in the google developer console:  i'm lost...  All I can think is that this is an html error?  Any idea what I can do to resolve this?

```
directive_normalizer.js:106
    Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:(…)
        DirectiveNormalizer.normalizeLoadedTemplate @ directive_normalizer.js:106
        DirectiveNormalizer.normalizeTemplateSync @ directive_normalizer.js:93
        DirectiveNormalizer.normalizeDirective @ directive_normalizer.js:69
        RuntimeCompiler._createCompiledTemplate @ runtime_compiler.js:231
        (anonymous function) @ runtime_compiler.js:159
        (anonymous function) @ runtime_compiler.js:155
        RuntimeCompiler._compileComponents @ runtime_compiler.js:154
        RuntimeCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents @ runtime_compiler.js:90
        RuntimeCompiler.compileModuleAsync @ runtime_compiler.js:81
        PlatformRef_._bootstrapModuleWithZone @ application_ref.js:328
        PlatformRef_.bootstrapModule @ application_ref.js:310
        (anonymous function) @ main.ts:12
        __webpack_require__ @ bootstrap c11ce27…:52
        (anonymous function) @ zone.js:1428
        __webpack_require__ @ bootstrap c11ce27…:52
        webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap c11ce27…:23
        (anonymous function) @ main.bundle.js:1
```

my component template:

```
<ul class="list-group">                        
    <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-success">Description</li>
    <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-info">{{product.description}}</li>
    <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-success">Pos Description</li>
    <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-info">{{product.POSDescription}}</li>
    <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-success">Pos Price</li>
    <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-info">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" />{{product.POSPrice}}
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-success">Stock On Hand</li>
    <li  class="list-group-item list-group-item-info">{{product.StockOnHand}}</li>                        
</ul>
```

my app.component.html template which is supposed to contain the product component:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-push-3">
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">        
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="barcode" placeholder="Enter Barcode" #barcode>    
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-submit btn-block" (click)="submitBarcode(barcode)">Submit</button>
</form>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <app-product [product]="product"></app-product>
</div>
```

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40445595/debugging-angular2-applications/40446307#40446307

Comment: @yurzui Thanks you just showed me something very useful:)  Please add it as an answer...  Turns out it was a self-closing <span element...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular2 provides very usefull information about exception. You should only use it correctly.
[image]

See also

- [Debugging Angular2 applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40445595/debugging-angular2-applications)